# Pause Recording on RN camera / React native

Tags: react-native, video-capture

I'am working ona React native project which has a video recording option.My requirement is that it should have a button to pause the recording. I'm able to record/stop a recording but I'am not able to pause the recording can someone please help with this.Iam usin RNCamera library for recording the video.

Comment: Hi, did you find any workaround for this requirement